# Is it possible to enable the Next button in the calendar, while using the endDate Script?

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

```js
$('.form_date').datetimepicker({
        language:  'fr',
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn:  0,
        autoclose: 1,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 2,
        minView: 2,
        forceParse: 0,
//        yearRange: '-99:-18',
        //endDate: e2,
        startDate: "1921-01-01 10:00",
        pickerPosition:'bottom-left',
//       yearRange: '1950:2013',
        endDate: '-18y'
    });
```

```html
<input class="form-control field1 form_date" onchange="showsunsign(), showseldate('bdate1')" data-date-format="dd-M-yyyy" data-link-field="dtp_input1" type="text" required autocomplete="off" data-link-format="dd-mmm-yyyy">
```

I am using end Date to display the 18-year complete date of birth.

When I used the endDate: '-18y' it would display the calendar till September 2003 month only.

Is it possible to enable the Next button for the selection of future dates in the calendar?.

If yes then can you help me out on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use method

```
$('.form_date').datetimepicker({
   ...
   onShow: function(date){
       //some logic
   }),
});
```

[More info here](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#runtime_options)

Comment: Thanks for your help! which logic I have to use to display the Next button and then can continue to view the future date and till the current date